# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null

Tags: java, url, apache-tika

For this link http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/09/02/uber-banned-across-germany-by-frankfurt-court/?partner=rss&emc=rss this code doesn`t work but if I put another for exemple: https://www.google.com everything is ok:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2014/09/02/uber-banned-across-germany-by-frankfurt-court/?partner=rss&emc=rss");
        URLConnection uc;
    uc = url.openConnection();
    uc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.16 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/10.0.648.205 Safari/534.16");
    uc.addRequestProperty("referer", "http://www.facebook.com");
    uc.connect();     

    this.input = uc.getInputStream();
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = http host = null
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:170)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:926)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2398)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1557)
    at UrlParser.<init>(UrlParser.java:48)
    at TikaParser.test_url_parser(TikaParser.java:186)
    at TikaParser.run(TikaParser.java:256)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 47):

I encountered this same exception when the URL started with `http:/` instead of `http://`. e.g. `http:/www.example.com`

This was in the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange()` method, so it's not quite the same context, but maybe a similar issue.

Comment: `http://` became `http:/` when I accidentally passed the URL in a `pathlib.Path()` in Python.

Comment: Yes... That's it. I should've looked more closely sooner, but didn't. Like you know when you're sure that something can't be the error. Definitely not. Until you think, once again, "Welcome to the IT" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Mostly this error occur due to incorrect url. Make sure the Url that you are hitting is correct.As wsams mentioned try to check the // in your url if it is correct or not.
Correct pattern is http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your proxy host is not set. Try setting it, then it should work.

See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) for more information on proxy properties.

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: try setting -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourproxyhost through the command line

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: In gradle-wrapper.properties just hav a look at distribution url.
Make it correct like this;

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```

Its working properly